# Highchart - change data series with link

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a chart with a data series (say qty and price of tomatoes grown in different countries) and now I want to change the data series to qty and price of grapes.

```
+--------------+
|              | TOMATOES [ SELECTED ]
|    CHART     | GRAPES
|              | RICE
+--------------+
```

Of course I could link to a new page (grapes.html) or use iframes. Preferably I can load a new data series.

A sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/cm5roecm/1/

EDIT: As per comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/cm5roecm/4/

Comment: Cannot these be different series in the same chart? And when showing one you hide the others?

Comment: Let me think about that. There will be 17 different "screens"; each with 4-7 stacked bar charts; each with 100s of items in the data series. That would be at least 10,000 items.

Comment: Hard to estimate the performance. Either that or you could do a bunch of `Series.remove()` and `chart.addSeries()` operations upon changing from tomatoes to grapes. That will also have some demand.

Comment: It seems like an interesting idea. I keep running into problems - such as losing formatting. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should be pretty easy to accomplish.

This is an update to older example I had that updates series data based on a select list, using the `series.setData()` method:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jEGUF/

It relies on predefining the data series as an array of arrays, but could also be easily adapted to load the new data via ajax.

There is also the `series.update()` method, and the `series.remove()` and `chart.addSeries()` methods that can all be used to accomplish this.